# Как сохранить постоянное направление тени при вращении предмета?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-animation

Например у `div` есть прямоугольная тень. При вращении прямоугольника происходит вращение направления прямоугольной тени, что вызывает проблемы, так как тень прямоугольника должна создать иллюзию освещения.

Пример:  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5h7z4swk/)

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
#box1 {
  background-color: #b00;
}
#box2 {
  background-color: #0b0;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
#box3 {
  background-color: #00b;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
#box4 {
  background-color: #b0b;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
#box6 {
  background-color: #0bb;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3"></div>
<div id="box4"></div>
<div id="box6"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ответ для решения этой проблемы должен выглядеть примерно так:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу повернуть `div` и сохранить прямоугольную тень от него в том же направлении?
Решение должно быть только -- `CSS`...

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Keep box-shadow direction consistent while rotating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35102216/7394871) от участника  [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558566/chris).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102216/keep-box-shadow-direction-consistent-while-rotating/35102375#35102375

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Размеры квадрата и его положение зададим родительскому блоку, а псевдоэлементы пусть их наследуют. «Блок-тень» немного сдвинем, добавим ему размытие (имитация тени) и будем вращать псевдоэлементы.

```css
body {
  background-color: #8694ef;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}

.square:before,
.square:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  filter: blur(8px);
  animation: rotate linear 5s infinite;
}

.square:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=square></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Сохранение  направления смещения прямоугольника-тени, согласованного во время вращения, реализуется с помощью `CSS-transforms`.

Этот подход основан на том, что фактически [transform origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) перемещается с помощью преобразований.

Это означает, что когда несколько преобразований установлены на один и тот же элемент, система координат каждого преобразования изменяется в соответствии с предыдущими.

В следующем примере синий элемент является псевдоэлементом, а тень - элементом `div`:

```css
div {
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  margin: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #000;
  animation: spinShadow 2s infinite;
  background-color: #000;
}
@keyframes spinShadow {
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:-5px; top:-5px;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(0deg);
  animation:inherit;
  animation-name: spinElt;
  background-color: #0bb;
}
@keyframes spinElt {
  to { transform: rotate(-360deg) translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Объяснение свойства `transition` для псевдоэлемента**
(см. Следующий фрагмент кода для иллюстрации этапов):

```
transform: rotate(-360deg) translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(360deg)
```

1. `rotate(-360deg)` - Счетчик вращение родительского элемента, чтобы
   сделать псевдоэлемент статическим
2. `translate (-10px, -10px)` - псевдоэлемент сдвигается, чтобы сделать
   смещение тени
3. `rotate(360deg)`, псевдоэлемент поворачивается в том же направлении,
   что и родительский элемент

**Чтобы увидеть все элементы откройте сниппет "на всю страницу"**

```css
div {
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  margin: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #000;
  animation: spinShadow 2s infinite;
  background-color: #000;
}
@keyframes spinShadow {
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:-5px; top:-5px;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  animation:inherit;
  background-color: #0bb;
}
#first:before{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  animation-name: first;
}  
@keyframes first {
  to { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
#second:before{
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-10px, -10px);
  animation-name: second;
}  
@keyframes second {
  to { transform: rotate(-360deg) translate(-10px, -10px); }
}
#complete:before{
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(0deg);
  animation-name: complete;
}  
@keyframes complete {
  to { transform: rotate(-360deg) translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Counter rotate:<div id="first"></div></li>
  <li>Translate :<div id="second"></div></li>
  <li>Rotate:<div id="complete"></div></li>
<ol>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35102375/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Вы также можете интегрировать направление прямоугольной тени внутри кадров анимации:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em ;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px 5px gray;
  animation: rte 5s infinite linear;
}

.red {
  background: red
}

.green {
  background: green;
  animation-delay:2s;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  animation-delay:4s;
}

.bob {
  background: #b0b;
  animation-delay:6s;
}

.cyan {
  background: cyan;
  animation-delay:8s;
}

@keyframes rte {
  25% {
    box-shadow:  15px -15px 15px 5px gray;
  }
  50% {
      box-shadow:  -15px -15px 15px 5px gray;
  }
  75% {
    box-shadow:  -15px 15px 15px 5px gray;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="bob"></div>
<div class="cyan"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35102729/7394871) от участника  [@G-Cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/g-cyrillus).</sub>

Comment: Этот вариант выглядит кривовато, тень как будто шагает.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko согласен - шаг вперед, два назад. Я бы сказал, что не шагает, а как бы возвращается, поджимается под фигуру. Свой вариант будешь пробовать?

Comment: спасибо, что спросили, только благодаря этому решил набросать свой вариант )